# Senig an HTTP request doesn't get me to the "service" function in my servlet

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I am trying to do a simple servlet connection socket,
I am able to see this webpage and able to get to my servlet(on another eclipse instance) breakpoint when using a web browser.
but when i try to perform the following function:

```
public void Connect() {
        try {
            String params = URLEncoder.encode("ID", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("test", "UTF-8");
            params += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("GOAL", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("Security", "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(_address);
            String host = url.getHost();
            int port = url.getPort();
            String path = url.getPath();

            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

            // Send headers
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
            wr.write("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            wr.write("Content-Length: " + params.length() + "\r\n");
            wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            wr.write("\r\n");

            // Send parameters
            wr.write(params);
            wr.flush();

            // Get response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            String answer = "";

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer += line;
            }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();

            if (answer.indexOf(resourceStrings.ACCESS_GRANTED) != -1)
            {
                _result = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            _result = false;
        }
    }
```

I just recieve the following answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8180/Admin/
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 15:00:28 GMT
Connection: close
```

without getting to my servlet code's breakpoint or retrieve any data from my "service" function in the servlet.

I am using Tomcat 7 if it makes any difference, do you have any idea what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of a GET request are sent by appending them to the URL, not in the body of the request.

Comment: The same thing happened to me when i used POST, so i am not sure it is the problem